# Quarterback Rating Java Data Type Error

Tags: java

I am writing code for standard NFL Quarterback rating (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passer_rating#Value_and_Limitations for my equations).  I have entered the following code in Java, but the max QBR it gives me is 152.0.  I think it has something to do with the data types I have chosen, but I am not sure.

```
public static double main(int comp, int att, int TD, int INTR, int YDS)

{
    double a = ((comp)/(att) - 0.3) * 5;

    double b = ((YDS)/(att)-3) * 0.25;

    double c = (20 * TD)/(att);

    double d = 2.375 - (25*INTR)/(att);

    double rating = ((Math.max (0, Math.min (a, 2.375)))
                    +
                    (Math.max (0, Math.min (b, 2.375)))
                    +
                    (Math.max (0, Math.min (c, 2.375)))
                    +
                    (Math.max (0, Math.min (d, 2.375))))
                    * (50/3);
    return (rating);
}
```

}

Comment: make the att data  type to float or double.

Answer (score 0):

since **TD** and **att** both are int though you assign the result of following line to a double variable you will not get correct value.
Therefore cast one value to a double
use

```
 double c = (double)(20 * TD)/(att);
```

instead of using

```
 double c = (20 * TD)/(att);
```